# How to change iframe size in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, webview

I'va created an web page and loaded it in android WebView.

HTML source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeIframeSize(height, width){
                var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
                iframe.height = height;
                iframe.width = width;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0"> 
        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1_cAHFx_vODxMGGGwhrrXx0rGiv0vs-GLsPRMTJ0COgg/viewform?embedded=true" width="360" height="515" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="iframe1" style="margin: 0; padding: 0"> Loading...   
        </iframe>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I loaded this page using this method:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://base", htmlSource, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

I want to change iframe size from Java code. I tried to do that using JavaScript:

```
DisplayMetrics metrix = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrix.widthPixels;
int height = metrix.heightPixels;
float density = metrix.density;

String func = "javascript:changeIframeSize(" +
        (int)(height / density - (75 + (hasAdView() ? 50 : 0))) +
        ", " +
        (int)(width / density) +
        ")";

webView.loadUrl(func);
```

But it does not work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try before loadUrl at first time:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled( true);
```

Comment: Oh my... How can i forget that... Thanks